# C# - Como limpar o "cache" do Visual Studio 2017 sem precisar fechar e reabrir o programa?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Quando faço uma alteração em uma biblioteca no Visual Studio Community 2017 preciso fechar o programa e abrir novamente para que as alterações tenham efeito.

A alteração que estou fazendo é a documentação de uma biblioteca (.dll) e gerando o arquivo .xml correspondente (marcando a checkbox em Propriedades > Build > Output).

Tentei o "Clean Solution" e o "Rebuild" na aplicação que está consumindo a biblioteca mas a documentação não é exibida na IDE até que eu a reinicie. Imagino que seja algum tipo de "cache". Existe alguma forma "simples" de resolver essa questão?

Comment: Tenta mudar de debug para release ou vice versa, e depois faz o clean

Comment: Você gera o xml através de uma custom tool ou pelo checkbox do output no build?

Comment: Pela checkbox mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Para limpar o cache do Visual Studio, acesse o caminho abaixo:

```
C:\Users\SeuUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

ou pelo executável:

```
%Temp%\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```